# Image not bouncing in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, bounce

I am doing a project of a mock up NPR page and I want to make the logo bounce however it's not doing so.

I'm pretty sure the syntax is right. I just need an extra eye to lead me in the right direction.

Here is my jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".nprLogo").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).stop().effect("bounce", 500);

            $(".nprLogo").mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).stop(true, true);

            });
        });
    });
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<table id="tableHeader">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <!-- NPR LOGO -->
            <img class="headerImages" class="nprLogo" src="images/nprlogo.png">
    </tr>
    </th>
</table>
```

I have it in a table because that was part of the instructions.

Comment: You have some improperly nested table markup there.

Comment: Still no luck..I tried inputting the revisions and adding http to the jQuery links and nothing.

Answer (score 2):

That's a jquery UI function, you need to include it in addition to jQuery:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

As a side note, your `</tr>` and `</th>` are in the wrong order, you need to have `</th>` first...